# Documentation for Apple's ithmb format?

Tags: ipod

I am looking for documentation of the ithmb format used by Apple for photos stored on an Apple iPod. I would be happy with source code or a description. The only "documentation" I can find is pre-compiled executables that crack out the JPEGs.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: There is an example of code [here](http://forums.ilounge.com/showthread.php?p=650968). Not sure about any documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a discussion in the ilounge forum a while ago, 
http://forums.ilounge.com/showthread.php?p=650968

and the ipodlinux wiki has some informations about the itunesDB (including the photo parts)
http://www.ipodlinux.org/wiki/ITunesDB

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the ipodlinux wiki. That's the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

According to the makers of FileJuicer (which can perform this conversion on a Mac),

> The ithmb files are compressed using 16 bits per pixel in YUV format for television and they are therefore a bit smaller than the converted TIFF files.

It appears that the **ithmb** format varies from device to device (iPod Photo, iPhone, etc.), so you'll probably have to manipulate things based on which device the file came from.

FileJuicer **ithmb** Format Page:
http://echoone.com/filejuicer/formats/ithmb

Wikipedia **YUV** Page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV

FOURCC **YUV/RGB** File Information:
http://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php
http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php